# How to pass multiple string values from one page to another?

Tags: c#, navigation, query-string, windows-phone-8.1

I figured out how to pass one value as a string from a text box from one page to another using a query string.

But I don't know how to pass multiple string values, for example I have a wrkTbx,rstTbx and roundTbx.

How do I pass all three values to another page?

This is my current implementation:

Workout page:

```
        private void appBarAddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?key=" + wrkTbx.Text, UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

MainPage:

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("key"))
            {
                string val = NavigationContext.QueryString["key"];
                MessageBox.Show("value is:  " + val);
            }

        }
```

Comment: [How to pass values Between ASP.NET WebPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate multiple QueryString parameters with an ampersand (`&`). But you also need to be sure to properly encode those values, because of special characters they may contain (like an ampersand, for example).

Here's a modified version of your code, that passes all the values you mentioned.

Workout page:

```
private void appBarAddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "/MainPage.xaml" +
        "?wrkTbx=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(wrkTbx.Text) +
        "&rstTbx=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(rstTbx.Text) +
        "&roundTbx=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(roundTbx.Text);

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

MainPage:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("wrkTbx"))
    {
        string wrkTbx = NavigationContext.QueryString["wrkTbx"];
        MessageBox.Show("wrkTbx value is: " + wrkTbx);
    }

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("rstTbx"))
    {
        string rstTbx = NavigationContext.QueryString["rstTbx"];
        MessageBox.Show("rstTbx value is: " + rstTbx);
    }

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("roundTbx"))
    {
        string roundTbx = NavigationContext.QueryString["roundTbx"];
        MessageBox.Show("roundTbx value is: " + roundTbx);
    }

}
```

Comment: The name 'server' doesn't exist. Is this available in windows phone 8.1? Do I have to add a using of some description?

Comment: I realized after I posted that code that it was using the ASP.NET version of UrlEncode. Check the modified "Workout page" code, and the "NOTE" I added above that, and see if that works.

Comment: Just tried the edited code and the System.web isn't recognized. Added a using.System. but no reference for .Web

Comment: Did you add a project reference to the `System.Web.dll` assembly? (Assuming it's even available in the "portable" version of the .NET framework that Windows Phone apps are limited to...)

Comment: I don't think its available, tried adding a reference in the solution explorer,but no System.Web

Comment: Okay, hopefully last update needed: Now it uses `System.Net.WebUtility`. That's in the `System.dll` assembly. According to the following page, it is supported by Windows Phone 8.1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It gives an error: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Wow, I left off the `.Text` property. Shame on me! Fixed now.

Comment: I implemented the above solution and the text box values are getting passed to the string variables in the other page.But how do I let other methods know about the strings rstTbx etc. When I reference them in a method outside of onNavigatedTo they are out of scope/not seen?

Comment: You could make them page-level variables or properties instead of method-level variables. Or you could set up a separate static or singleton class with properties for each of those values, which would allow you to share them application-wide. Or there may be some other sort of Session-like feature for WP8 apps, but if so, I don't recall what that may be.

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("Default2.aspx?wrkTbx.Text={0}&rstTbx.Text={1}&roundTbx.Text={2}",Server.UrlEncode(wrkTbx.Text),Server.UrlEncode(rstTbx.Text),Server.UrlEncode(roundTbx.Text)));


Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["wrkTbx.Text"]);
Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["rstTbx.Text"]);
Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["roundTbx.Text"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

for wp8

```
//send data
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?key=" + wrkTbx.Text + "&key2=" + wrkTbx2.Text, UriKind.Relative));

//retrive the information 
string key,stringKey2;
int key2;
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("key", out key)){
  // use key value
}
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("key2", out stringKey2)){
    key2 = Int32.Parse(stringKey2); // use key2 value
}
```

for winndows phone8.1

```
public class model
{
   public string key{ get; set; }
   public int key2{ get; set; }
}

//send data
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), new PassedData { key= "my name", key2= 10 });

// get data
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e){
    model= e.Parameter as model;
}
```